# problems with table

Tags: tables

I dont know how to make my tabel fit my document, can anyone help me? - Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|l|l|@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Kategori}                                                                                                                               & \textbf{Piezoelektrisk generator}                                                                                                                                                                                                                          & \textbf{Hydraulisk generator}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \textbf{Elektrisk generator}                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Kompleksitet \\ Her er ikke nævnt materialer hvorpå/i de enkelte dele\\ er monteret eller samlet\end{tabular}        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Til en generator, baseret på piezoelektriske materialer,\\ skal bruges et piezo elektrisk materiale og en kondensator\end{tabular}                                                                                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Til et \\ hydraulisk system skal bruges rørføring til hydraulikvæske, et ventilstyrehus,\\ en cylinder og en turbine samt en ensretter\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Til et\\ elektrisk generatorsystem skal bruges en spole, en bevægelig magnet og en\\ ensretter. En konverter som konverterer vertikal bevægelse til rotation\end{tabular}                 \\ \midrule
Bevægelige dele                                                                                                                                 & Kræver en ydre mekanisk påvirkning                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}For at et hydraulisk system kan fungere, skal der anvendes\\ stempler, ventiler og turbine\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                   & Kræver at magneten kan bevæge sig gennem spolen                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Nyttevirkning\\ Alle tre generatorer vil have et tab af energi i form\\ af varmeudvikling ved friktion.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Producerer jævnstrøm, der via kondensator kan forbindes til\\ bilens elektriske system.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Da der produceres vekselstrøm, vil der være tab i\\ ensretteren. Endvidere vil der være et energitab i alle de bevægelige dele\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Da der produceres vekselstrøm, vil der være tab i\\ ensretteren. Da magneten er bevægelig, vil der være et tab af energi der.\end{tabular}                                                \\ \midrule
Anvendelig strømproduktion                                                                                                                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Jævnstrøm,\\ kræver en kondensator anordning\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                       & Vekselstrøm, kræver en ensretter.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    & Vekselstrøm, kræver en ensretter.                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Vægt\\ For at udnytte energien i bilens affjedringssystem, høstes\\ der på alle fire hjulophæng\end{tabular}         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Kan produceres i lette materialer. Systemet skal placeres\\ lokalt. Det vil sige en generator ved hvert hjulophæng.\end{tabular}                                                                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Systemet skal, for at klare et vist tryk i cylinderen,\\ produceres af metal, og der skal laves en del rørføring. Ved hjælp af\\ rørføring, kan et centralt system høste energien fra alle fire hjulophæng. Der\\ skal dog monteres en til to cylindre for hvert hjulophæng.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Magnet\\ og spole vil være af metal. Systemet skal placeres lokalt. Det vil sige en\\ generator ved hvert hjulophæng.\end{tabular}                                                        \\ \midrule
Vedligehold                                                                                                                                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Der behøves ikke en mekanisk påvirkning fra hjulophænget,\\ hvilket gør det nemmere at have i et lukket system.,Systemet kan derfor på- og afmonteres uden ændring i bilens\\ konstruktion\end{tabular}                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}I\\ tilfælde af lækage lukker høster systemet fuldstændig ned. Et total lukket\\ system er nødvendigt. Hvis en defekt indtræder, kræves der en systematisk\\ gennemgang og fejlfinding af systemet\end{tabular}                                                                           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Da hver generator kræver et totalt lukket miljø, for at\\ holde det rent, vil det kræve en indkapsling. Dette besværliggøres af den\\ mekaniske påvirkning fra hjulophænget.\end{tabular} \\ \midrule
Påvirkning af bilens stabilitet                                                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Kan\\ monteres uafhængig af bilens affjedringssystem, uden en mekanisk påvirkning fra\\ hjulophænget. Da systemet kan produceres i lette materialer, vil det have en lavere\\ negativ effekt på bilens stabilitet.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Konstruktionen af affjedringssystem skal ændres, for ikke\\ stabiliteten forringes.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Generatoren skal mekanisk tilkobles hjulophænget, hvilket\\ vil have en negativ effekt på bilens affjedring.\end{tabular}                                                                 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: How big is your physical page (A4? something else?), and what are the margin settings of your document?

Comment: A4 @Mico margin: \setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.0cm}{*}

Answer (score 1):

Your table is too big to fit on one page. You should take a look on `longtable`. In order to get automated line-breaking, you could use a `p`-column with a certain width. As you want to use the full width of your text area, I made a solution using `tabularx`. It sets the table width to the maximum possible. You might also want to consider to type everything in landscape mode.

The `X`-columns will set each column to the same width. While this is easy to type, it might look bad if the content of the columns differs a lot in quantity. It is left to you to decide, how the column widths should be distributed.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{showframe} % for demo
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}L}\toprule
        \textbf{Kategori} & \textbf{Piezoelektrisk generator} & \textbf{Hydraulisk generator} & \textbf{Elektrisk generator} \\\midrule
        Kompleksitet \hfil Her er ikke nævnt materialer hvorpå/i de enkelte dele er monteret eller samlet & Til en generator, baseret på piezoelektriske materialer, skal bruges et piezo elektrisk materiale og en kondensator & Til et hydraulisk system skal bruges rørføring til hydraulikvæske, et ventilstyrehus, en cylinder og en turbine samt en ensretter & Til et elektrisk generatorsystem skal bruges en spole, en bevægelig magnet og en ensretter. En konverter som konverterer vertikal bevægelse til rotation \\\midrule
        Bevægelige dele & Kræver en ydre mekanisk påvirkning & For at et hydraulisk system kan fungere, skal der anvendes stempler, ventiler og turbine                                                                                                                                                                                   & Kræver at magneten kan bevæge sig gennem spolen \\\midrule
        Nyttevirkning\hfil Alle tre generatorer vil have et tab af energi i form af varmeudvikling ved friktion. & Producerer jævnstrøm, der via kondensator kan forbindes til bilens elektriske system. & Da der produceres vekselstrøm, vil der være tab i ensretteren. Endvidere vil der være et energitab i alle de bevægelige dele & Da der produceres vekselstrøm, vil der være tab i ensretteren. Da magneten er bevægelig, vil der være et tab af energi der. \\\midrule
        Anvendelig strømproduktion & Jævnstrøm, kræver en kondensator anordning & Vekselstrøm, kræver en ensretter. & Vekselstrøm, kræver en ensretter. \\\midrule
        ... & ... & ... & ... \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]